# Calculate the integral $ \int \frac{1}{(t+s+1)^{3t}} * (\frac{s+1}{t+s+1})^{3t(s+1)}ds$

Tags: integration

I have a problem to calculate two integrals:
$$ \int \frac{1}{(t+s+1)^{3t}} * (\frac{s+1}{t+s+1})^{3t(s+1)}ds$$
and
$$\int e^{-3((t+1)\ln(t+1)-t)}dt$$

First integral I got from this
$$\int e^{-3(t(\ln(t+s+1)-1)+(s+1)\ln(\frac{t+s+1}{s+1}))}ds$$

Any help?

Comment: For the first one, any idea for computing it if $t=1$. Are you sure that the problem is not with definite integrals ?

Comment: So I just have to put in $t=1$ and calculate? What about for any $t$? There is a problem for me.

Comment: I meant : are you able to compute the antiderivative for $t=1$ ? Not me. What about my question ?

Comment: For $t=1$ I can calculate the integral if you are asking about that. I am asking you what about for any $t$, there I find the problem?

Comment: Could you then add in the post what is $$I_1=\int (s+1)^{3 s+3} (s+2)^{-3 (s+2)} \, ds$$